# How to use plain javascript in nuxtjs?

Tags: nuxt.js

Can I use ECMAScript 2017 **javascript** **in** nuxt pages like **index.vue**?

Do I have to use `export default` ?
Where should I put my code?

I found how to use jsx in docs but I think there must be a simple way to use javascript.

https://nuxtjs.org/faq/jsx#how-to-use-jsx-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Vue single file component with the plain old javascript object. See the documentation on https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#pages

```js
<template>
  <h1 class="red">Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  asyncData (context) {
    // called every time before loading the component
    // as the name said, it can be async
    // Also, the returned object will be merged with your data object
    return { name: 'World' }
  },
  fetch () {
    // The `fetch` method is used to fill the store before rendering the page
  },
  head () {
    // Set Meta Tags for this Page
  },
  // and more functionality to discover
  ...
}
</script>

<style>
.red {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Or you can use ES classes with `nuxt-class-component` https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-class-component

```js
<template>
  <h1 class="red">Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'nuxt-class-component'
import {
  State,
  Getter,
  Action,
  Mutation,
  namespace
} from 'vuex-class'

const Module = namespace('path/to/module')

@Component({
  props: {
    propMessage: String
  }
})
export class MyComp extends Vue {
  @State('foo') stateFoo
  @State(state => state.bar) stateBar
  @Getter('foo') getterFoo
  @Action('foo') actionFoo
  @Mutation('foo') mutationFoo
  @Module.Getter('foo') moduleGetterFoo
  @Module.Action('foo') moduleActionFoo

  // If the argument is omitted, use the property name
  // for each state/getter/action/mutation type
  @State foo
  @Getter bar
  @Action baz
  @Mutation qux

  // initial data
  msg = 123

  // use prop values for initial data
  helloMsg = 'Hello, ' + this.propMessage

  // lifecycle hooks
  created () {
    this.stateFoo // -> store.state.foo
    this.stateBar // -> store.state.bar
    this.getterFoo // -> store.getters.foo
    this.actionFoo({ value: true }) // -> store.dispatch('foo', { value: true })
    this.mutationFoo({ value: true }) // -> store.commit('foo', { value: true })
    this.moduleGetterFoo // -> store.getters['path/to/module/foo']
  }

  mounted () {
    this.greet()
  }

  fetch () {
    // fetch data
  }

  async asyncData () {
    // async fetching data
  }

  // computed
  get computedMsg () {
    return 'computed ' + this.msg
  }

  // method
  greet () {
    alert('greeting: ' + this.msg)
  }
}
</script>
```